# Moving data across environments

Tags: linux, rsync, scp, data-transfer

I have a very lame situation at the moment about moving data across environments at work.

These data are database dumps, Solr indexes or simple images. Our process is: "tarball the data" + "rsync/scp the data to another environment/machine" + "unpack the data".

The size of those data vary from a few Gigabytes to a max of ~1 Terabytes.

Some of the processes are "scripted" other still need manual processing.

Anyway the main problem is the time to pack/unpack and rsync the data.

Considering performance and "automatism", are there better strategies to move data around?

Answer (score 1):

You could mount that remote filesystem with [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) for example.

`sshfs user@remotehoste:<remotepath> <localpath>`

Then you can symlink the data where do you need it or access them right there.

`ln -s <mountpont/file> <targetlocation>`

But it depends on what exactly you want to do with this data.

Comment: I was thinking about a similar solution. The data are mostly "read only" data. It means they will be accessed just to be read (so no writing).

Comment: Then I think this would be the best solution, better than pack/unpack everytime and if it is read only you will not get any problems with that.

Comment: how can data be mostly "read only"?  You either have permission to modify the data or you don't have the permission( i.e. read-only).

Comment: He meant what he is doing with the data and not the access rights I think ...

Comment: @Ramhound as mstruebing says I meant how the data are used like images that need to be displayed or Solr indexes to search in.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility depending on what you are trying to do is to replicate data at the block level - for example using DRBD or MARS on LVM and use snapshotting for PITR and/or modifying data off a copy of the image - just be aware that LVM snapshots slow IO down quite a lot on the subsystem being snapshotted.